# University AT city name

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was wondering if anyone would care to explain why some universities use AT in  their names (University of Illinois AT Chicago/ University AT Buffalo) when the preposition used with cities is usually IN. Is that supposed to imply AT that campus or something of the kind??

thanks a lot

ps: I have checked Shoe's answer to the question "at vs in followed by a city name" and I don't quite feel it fits the bill here. I am aware of Yule's  explanation about the speaker's point of view in "Explaining English Grammar" , which, by the way, gives an example very similar to Shoe's, but I don't think that example actually fits here. Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help]; asking for "thoughts" is not acceptable in our format. Looking up *at* in the dictionary indicates that it can be used to indicate that something is in, on, or near something; there is nothing that makes *in* preferable to *at* for universities, and sometimes *at* is more accurate— the University of Arkansas at Monticello is not only *in* Monticello, but has campuses *in* Crossett and McGehee as well. *At* is in fact conventional; the only exception I can think of is *Columbia University in the City of New York*.

Comment: In a number of cases, the campuses aren't actually IN the cities (or weren't when founded), but nearby.

Comment: @choster. I was not aware that I wasn't allowed to ask for "thoughts". if you read my question you will see I'm actually asking "why", so I don't feel I had to be reproached because of an afterthought added under the post scriptum. I had actually looked up "at" in the dictionary, but I didn't think "near" applied because I know some of those campuses to be IN the actual city (the University of Illinois at Chicago, for example, has its campus right in the centre of the city). I also looked up information about other universities that use "at" in their names and found that many are in the cities

Comment: @choster. I had also found two examples using IN (Columbia University in New York AND Stanford in New York). So, as you see, I had done my research AND checked the other questions from this forum before asking my question. Thanks for the reply though. I did not know some of them had campuses located in different towns. perhaps that explains why some of them choose to use "at"...

Comment: University of X **in** Y implies that the entire university is in Y. But when a university is spread over multiple locations, **at** is used to indicate the location of a particular campus.

Comment: And another *in*: *Washington University in St. Louis*.

Comment: It's not systematic at all. Consider the University of Alabama System. UAH is the *University of Alabama **in** Huntsville*, but UAB is the *University of Alabama **at** Birmingham* (UAB's campus is downtown, so *at* doesn't just mean near but not in the city).

Answer (score 0):

State universities in the United States are organized slightly differently than in other countries: see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_university_system) for a brief overview.

In particular (from the wiki page link above):

> A state university system normally means a single legal entity and
>   administration, but may consist of several institutions, each with its
>   own identity as a university.

This means that, for example, **University of Maryland at College Park** does *not* refer to the **University of Maryland**. The University of Maryland is the single legal entity/administration for the Maryland state university system).

As such, the focus is on the fact that it's a *branch* of the university, not on where the branch is located.

When using "in" in a sentence, that the sentence focuses on the location, whereas "at" focuses more on adding a location to where something happened.

Compare the following sentences:

- I went swimming in the pool.
- I went swimming at the pool.

The first sentence places the emphasis on *where* we swam, whereas the second has more of an emphasis on the fact that we went swimming -- at the pool.

Comment: This answer does not make sense with Alabama. The University of Alabama is the campus located in Tuscaloosa. The University of Alabama at Birmingham is the campus located in Birmingham. The University of Alabama in Huntsville is the campus located in Huntsville. All three (UA, UAH, UAB) are campuses in the University of Alabama System.  There is no actual systematic pattern.

Comment: @guifa, that's a good point! Could you please then offer another answer for this question? That is, after all, the whole point of this site.. :)

Comment: @guifa, the "University of Alabama in Huntsville" is actually a really interesting case: there's no reason I can think of for the name to use "in" instead of "at". However, UAH is much smaller than the other 2 UA campuses (with regards to both enrollment and budget/endowment). Furthermore, UAH began as a location of UA and only later became an indepdent campus -- this suggests (to me) that the use of "in" came from the fact that the original intention for the location was not as an independent branch.